# Classification and random forests in Python: predictions are the same regardless of predictors

Tags: python, cart

I'm working with a small data set of 4 categorical predictors, one binary outcome, and ~90k observations. I've tried fitting a random forest classifier mimicking the iris example from http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html. However, my challenge is that my predicted values are all the same: 0. I'm new to Python, but familiar with R. Not sure if this is a coding mistake, or if this means my data is trash. Choosing random forests for variable selection before doing a logistic regression.

Please me know if you need more information. Not sure how to provide data for a MWE.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
data = train_df[cols_to_keep]
data = data.join(dummySubTypes.ix[:, 1:])
data = data.join(dummyLicenseTypes.ix[:, 1:])
data['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(data)) <= .75
#data['type'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(data['type'],["Type1","Type1"])
data.head()
Mytrain, Mytest = data[data['is_train']==True], data[data['is_train']==False]
Myfeatures = data.columns[1:5] # string of feature names: subtype dummy     variables
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2)
y, _ = pd.factorize(Mytrain['type'])
rf.fit(Mytrain[Myfeatures], y)
data.target_names = np.asarray(list(set(data['type'])))
preds = data.target_names[rf.predict(Mytest[Myfeatures])]
```

Predictions of only one class, Type1:

```
In[583]: pd.crosstab(Mytest['type'], preds, rownames=['actual'], colnames ['preds'])
Out[582]: 
preds          Type1
actual                   
Type1          17818
Type2          7247
```

Update:
First few rows of data:

```
In[670]: Mytrain[Myfeatures].head()
Out[669]: 
subtype_INDUSTRIAL  subtype_INSTITUTIONAL  subtype_MULTIFAMILY  \
0                   0                      0                    0   
1                   0                      0                    0   
2                   0                      0                    0   
3                   0                      0                    0   
4                   0                      0                    0   

subtype_SINGLE FAMILY / DUPLEX  
0                               0  
1                               0  
2                               0  
3                               1  
4                               1
```

When I predict on the training inputs, I get predictions of only one class:

```
In[675]: np.bincount(rf.predict(Mytrain[Myfeatures]))
Out[674]: array([    0, 75091])
```

Comment: Without the data, it's a little hard to see what's going on. Can you post e.g. the first few rows of `Mytrain[Myfeatures]`? Also, what are the label portions of the training data (`np.bincount(y)`)? What happens if you predict on the training inputs?

Comment: It seems that the model can't learn anything, so it's defaulting to the more-common label. You can try `class_weight='balanced'` or `'balanced_subsample'` to try to account for the class imbalance in your training data, or try increasing `n_estimators` from the default of 10 to say 100, or try tweaking the other parameters of the model....